# HTML page only displays MS Mincho Japanese font in all Windows browsers

Tags: html, css, windows, fonts

On my personal website, I created an HTML page that displays Japanese text. 
I used the following font families.

```
font-family: Osaka, "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif;
```

I've put this both in my CSS file and tried nesting it in a  statement. All browsers display the fonts correctly in OS X and Linux, but all Windows browsers will only display MS Mincho font.

Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: Well, is any of the other fonts installed on Windows?

Comment: You have to check if your windows unicode supports that font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A browser can only use a font if that font is installed on the machine on which the browser is running. If the font is not installed it tries the next one in the font-family list and if that one is not installed it tries the next and so on until it gets a font that the machine has installed. It then used this font.

If you want a particular font to be used by the browsers then you need to download that font to the machine using the using the [@fontface](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) and you can use a tool like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate all the correct CSS for you.

Be aware that most fonts installed on machines are subject to copyright and just ripping them from your machine and shipping them down to any old machine is in violation of that copyright. But there are many royalty free fonts out there that may do the job.